# 'http:/***.168.**.8:***/UploadedFiles/CustomerKYC/Photo/134_26581.jpg' is not a valid virtual path

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am getting the exception http:/***.168.11.8:***/UploadedFiles/CustomerKYC/Photo/134_26581.jpg' is not a valid virtual path when I write either WriteFile or TranferFile in the following code. Please give me a code fix.

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" +NavigateURLID.Value);
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(url));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

I need the file from the url to be downloaded. They are all image files only(jpg)

Comment: The string passed to MapPath should be only _/UploadedFiles/CustomerKYC/Photo/134_26581.jpg_

Comment: What does `url` contain?

Comment: My Url contains http://***.168.11.8:***/UploadedFiles/CustomerKYC/Photo/134_26581.jpg. I tried without Server.mapPath as well but getting the same error msg. When it comes after Response.WriteFile the URL gets converted into  http:/.168.11.8:/******* that is only a single slash after http:/ but I am passing an url with double slash http:// . Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer after searching in Internet. The code is.

```
    WebClient req=new WebClient();
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Buffer= true;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" +strURL + "\"");
    byte[] data=req.DownloadData(strURL);
    response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code will help

```
Response.ContentType = ContentType;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

Reference url: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-files-from-Folder-Directory-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx